# C++11 / Generated constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been working on a C++ project started by someone else (who left the company). He has written a piece of code which seems to work pretty well but I cannot understand it.

Here is below a simplified version of the code:

There are two classes :

```
class Algo_t {
protected :
    Matrix_t m_Matrix ;
public:
    Algo_t(Matrix_t && Matrix) {
        DoSomething();
    }
};

class Matrix_t {
protected :
    std::ifstream & m_iftsream ;
public:
    Matrix_t(std::ifstream && ifstream) {
        DoSomething();
    }
};
```

In the main:

There is the following call in the main function:

```
char * pMyFileName = agrv[1] ;
Algo_t MyAlgo(ifstream(pMyFileName));
```

First I was very surprised that the code compiled without any error because there is no constructor of `Algo_t` taking `ifstream` as a parameter. 
I was more surprised to  notice that this code works very well.

Are the constructor generated by the compiler or there is some new feature introduced by C++11 (with the rvalue...)?

Comment: Maybe class `Matrix_t` has an `ifstream`-casting operator, or a constructor which takes `ifstream`? Oh, heck, it does... That explains it...

Comment: Your simplified version does not compile even after fixing some of the obvious errors.

Comment: This is (almost) the same behavior as when you construct a structure taking a `std::string` with a `const char []`, e.g. `std::stringstream("Hello World!")` - You don't need to explicitly do `std::stringstream(std::string("Hello World!"))`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++ you are allowed up to one user defined conversion.  You cannot directly construct a `Algo_t` from a `ifstream` but you can construct a `Matrix_t` with a `ifstream`.  So in

```
Algo_t MyAlgo(ifstream(pMyFileName));
```

The compiler construct a temporary `Matrix_t`(your one user defined conversion) and then you use that temporary to construct `MyAlgo`

Comment: Up to one? What happens if we try to use more?

Comment: @CinCout It will not work.  Lets say you had another class `Foo` that can be constructed from a `Algo_t`.  `Foo MyFoo(ifstream(pMyFileName));` would not work.

Comment: Thats oddly formulated @NathanOliver in your answser, but it is correct.

Answer (score 4):

As explained [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/):

> Single-argument constructors: allow implicit conversion from a
>   particular type to initialize an object.

Hence, there is an implicit conversion option from  `ifstream` to `Matrix_t` due to the constructor:

```
Matrix_t(std::ifstream && ifstream)
```

So when you called:

```
Algo_t MyAlgo(ifstream(pMyFileName));
```

the `ifstream(pMyFileName)` object convert to `Matrix_t` object and then used by the constructor `Algo_t(Matrix_t && Matrix)`

Answer (score 3):

Your matrix constructor is implicitly called, as it takes `ifstream&&`. If you make it explicit, it wouldn't work:

```
explicit Matrix_t(std::ifstream && ifstream) {
    DoSomething();
}
```