# Unclear type conversion/promotion

Tags: c++

The below code compiles and runs without warning.
It's not clear to me what kind of conversion goes on in the call to `func`. The function expects a reference to type `B`, yet it accepts a pointer to type `A`. When removing the constructor `B(PA A)` the compilation fails, claiming failure to initialize reference type:

> Invalid initialization of reference of type 'const B&' from expression of type 'PA {aka A*}'

I don't see why the constructor is invoked in the first place instead of compilation failure. Any explanation to this?

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct A
{
    int x;
    int y;
} *PA;

class B
{
    public:
        B(PA pa):m_pa(pa){}
        int getPa() const{return m_pa->x;}
    private:
        PA m_pa;
};

void func(const B& b)
{
    std::cout << b.getPa();
}

int main()
{
    A a = {5,7};
    PA pA = &a;

    func(pA);       //Why does this compile and what is the outcome??
    return 0;
}
```

Live: https://ideone.com/y8Z2O9

Comment: What is surprising? `B` can be constructed from a `PA` and the function wants a `B`.  You are allowed up to one user defined conversion.

Comment: If you wish to only enable explicit conversions from `A*` to `B`, declare `B`'s constructor as `explicit`.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699814/c11-genrated-constructor

Comment: But func accepts reference, not value.

Comment: `B` or `func`?  `func` takes a `const &` so it can bind to temporaries.  Change it to `void func(B& b)` and you will get a error.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry, I meant func (edited). Yes, forgot that const ref can bind to temporaries. So if I get it correctly, there is a temporary B object being constructed upon call to func (with lifetime bound to life time of func)?

Comment: Yep.  You get up to one conversion so the compiler does that to get it to work.

Comment: But how does it decide whether the conversion is legal? The only connection between B and A* is the fact that B's constructor can accept A*. I don't seem to find this defined in spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/):

> Single-argument constructors: allow implicit conversion from a
>   particular type to initialize an object.

Hence, there is an implicit conversion option from  `PA` to `B` due to the constructor:

```
    B(PA pa)
```

So when you called:

```
    func(pA)
```

the `pA` pointer converted to `B` object and then used by `func`

(similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699814/c11-genrated-constructor/38699910#38699910))